# How to pass variable in @Html.partial

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How to pass variable in `@Html.partial`?

Index.cshtml

```
var message = 'select record';

@Html.Partial("_UsermangerMessageBox", message);
```

_UsermangerMessageBox.cshtml

```
@model string
$('<div id="umPopup">@Model.ToString()</div>').dialog({
            modal: true,
            dialogClass: 'dialogue-border deletePopup',
            title: "Confirmation",
            resizable: false,
            open: function () {
                $(this).html(message);
            },
            buttons: [{
                text: 'OK',
                'class': 'btn btn-primary',
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            }]
        });
```

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: You're passing `message` as the model, so just use the `Model` keyword in the partial to access it. If this isn't working for you then you need to provide much more information

Comment: variable cannot to be access that partial view you need to set class object.
if you still want to access 'message' variable value, just go through view.bag .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.0